# Load Preset and execute Function or Operator

Tags: python

I googled now for hours and hours, but couldn't find something near to this Task.

When I make a Preset-System like this here:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, Menu
from bl_operators.presets import AddPresetBase


class OBJECT_MT_display_presets(Menu):
    bl_label = "Object Display Presets"
    preset_subdir = "object/display"
    preset_operator = "script.execute_preset"
    draw = Menu.draw_preset


class AddPresetObjectDisplay(AddPresetBase, Operator):
    '''Add a Object Display Preset'''
    bl_idname = "camera.object_display_preset_add"
    bl_label = "Add Object Display Preset"
    preset_menu = "OBJECT_MT_display_presets"

    # variable used for all preset values
    preset_defines = [
        "obj = bpy.context.object"
    ]

    # properties to store in the preset
    preset_values = [
        "obj.display_type",
        "obj.show_bounds",
        "obj.display_bounds_type",
        "obj.show_name",
        "obj.show_axis",
        "obj.show_wire",
    ]

    # where to store the preset
    preset_subdir = "object/display"


# Display into an existing panel
def panel_func(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    row = layout.row(align=True)
    row.menu(OBJECT_MT_display_presets.__name__, text=OBJECT_MT_display_presets.bl_label)
    row.operator(AddPresetObjectDisplay.bl_idname, text="", icon='ZOOM_IN')
    row.operator(AddPresetObjectDisplay.bl_idname, text="", icon='ZOOM_OUT').remove_active = True


classes = (
    OBJECT_MT_display_presets,
    AddPresetObjectDisplay,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.OBJECT_PT_display.prepend(panel_func)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    bpy.types.OBJECT_PT_display.remove(panel_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I want to add an Operator or a Function that is called every time a Preset is loaded. It should not be called, when a Preset is added or removed - only when its loaded.
But because there is no execute() method in the Preset-System, I got no Idea where to put the Operator-Call in to.
I was also searching to append something to an execute-method but I didn't find anything.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If its written in python can be found with a little digging.**

The key here is in the menu, you are defining which operator to use to execute presets

```
    preset_operator = "script.execute_preset"
```

If we can find it in `bpy.types` then it has a python module

```
>>> bpy.ops.script.execute_preset.idname()
'SCRIPT_OT_execute_preset'

>>> bpy.types.SCRIPT_OT_execute_preset.__module__
'bl_operators.presets'
```

and there it is in *`2.91/scripts/startup/bl_operators/presets.py`*

```
class ExecutePreset(Operator):
    """Execute a preset"""
    bl_idname = "script.execute_preset"
    bl_label = "Execute a Python Preset"

    filepath: StringProperty(
        subtype='FILE_PATH',
        options={'SKIP_SAVE'},
    )
    menu_idname: StringProperty(
        name="Menu ID Name",
        description="ID name of the menu this was called from",
        options={'SKIP_SAVE'},
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        from os.path import basename, splitext
        filepath = self.filepath

        # change the menu title to the most recently chosen option
        preset_class = getattr(bpy.types, self.menu_idname)
        preset_class.bl_label = bpy.path.display_name(basename(filepath))

        ext = splitext(filepath)[1].lower()

        if ext not in {".py", ".xml"}:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "unknown filetype: %r" % ext)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if hasattr(preset_class, "reset_cb"):
            preset_class.reset_cb(context)

        if ext == ".py":
            try:
                bpy.utils.execfile(filepath)
            except Exception as ex:
                self.report({'ERROR'}, "Failed to execute the preset: " + repr(ex))

        elif ext == ".xml":
            import rna_xml
            rna_xml.xml_file_run(context,
                                 filepath,
                                 preset_class.preset_xml_map)

        if hasattr(preset_class, "post_cb"):
            preset_class.post_cb(context)

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

re-write another operator, using same properties,  to do whatever floats your boat when your preset is loaded, and tell the system to use it instead

```
preset_operator = "script.execute_preset_float_boat_version"
```

Ok, since we are no longer using the default operator, we can set the defaults for the operator in the draw preset method of menu class

```
>>> bpy.types.Menu.draw_preset(
draw_preset(self, _context)
Define these on the subclass:
- preset_operator (string)
- preset_subdir (string)
Optionally:
- preset_add_operator (string)
- preset_extensions (set of strings)
- preset_operator_defaults (dict of keyword args)
```

**Define the callbacks**

Looking at the operator code, notice two callback functions are run, one before the preset is loaded `reset_cb` and one after `post_cb`.  Have added these two classmethods to Menu to print to console when called.

so in full

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, Menu
from bl_operators.presets import AddPresetBase
from bpy.props import StringProperty

class ExecutePreset(Operator):
    """Execute a preset"""
    bl_idname = "script.execute_preset_float_boat"
    bl_label = "Execute a Python Preset"

    filepath: StringProperty(
        subtype='FILE_PATH',
        options={'SKIP_SAVE'},
    )
    menu_idname: StringProperty(
        name="Menu ID Name",
        description="ID name of the menu this was called from",
        options={'SKIP_SAVE'},
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        from os.path import basename, splitext
        filepath = self.filepath

        # change the menu title to the most recently chosen option
        preset_class = getattr(bpy.types, self.menu_idname)
        preset_class.bl_label = bpy.path.display_name(basename(filepath))

        ext = splitext(filepath)[1].lower()

        if ext not in {".py", ".xml"}:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "unknown filetype: %r" % ext)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if hasattr(preset_class, "reset_cb"):
            preset_class.reset_cb(context)

        if ext == ".py":
            try:
                bpy.utils.execfile(filepath)
            except Exception as ex:
                self.report({'ERROR'}, "Failed to execute the preset: " + repr(ex))

        elif ext == ".xml":
            import rna_xml
            rna_xml.xml_file_run(context,
                                 filepath,
                                 preset_class.preset_xml_map)

        if hasattr(preset_class, "post_cb"):
            preset_class.post_cb(context)

        return {'FINISHED'}

class OBJECT_MT_display_presets(Menu):
    bl_label = "Object Display Presets"
    preset_subdir = "object/display"
    preset_operator = "script.execute_preset_float_boat"
    preset_operator_defaults = {
            "menu_idname" : 'OBJECT_MT_display_presets'
            }
    draw = Menu.draw_preset
    @classmethod
    def reset_cb(self, context):
        print("Reset")
    @classmethod        
    def post_cb(self, context):
        print("Post Callback")


class AddPresetObjectDisplay(AddPresetBase, Operator):
    '''Add a Object Display Preset'''
    bl_idname = "camera.object_display_preset_add"
    bl_label = "Add Object Display Preset"
    preset_menu = "OBJECT_MT_display_presets"

    # variable used for all preset values
    preset_defines = [
        "obj = bpy.context.object"
    ]

    # properties to store in the preset
    preset_values = [
        "obj.display_type",
        "obj.show_bounds",
        "obj.display_bounds_type",
        "obj.show_name",
        "obj.show_axis",
        "obj.show_wire",
    ]

    # where to store the preset
    preset_subdir = "object/display"


# Display into an existing panel
def panel_func(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    row = layout.row(align=True)
    row.menu(OBJECT_MT_display_presets.__name__, text=OBJECT_MT_display_presets.bl_label)
    row.operator(AddPresetObjectDisplay.bl_idname, text="", icon='ZOOM_IN')
    row.operator(AddPresetObjectDisplay.bl_idname, text="", icon='ZOOM_OUT').remove_active = True


classes = (
    ExecutePreset,
    OBJECT_MT_display_presets,
    AddPresetObjectDisplay,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.OBJECT_PT_display.prepend(panel_func)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    bpy.types.OBJECT_PT_display.remove(panel_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Sounds great, but for now it looks like I made something wrong. What I did:
- I made a new Operator with a copy of the ExecutePreset Operator, renamed it.
- registered it
- made a new Menu with the new made preset_operator.
- Put the new menu into the row.menu() in the Panel


But now there is an Error when using it that way in blender :


File ... 2.91\scripts\addons\Render_Preset_Addon\addon\operator\RPA_Execute_Preset.py", line 28, in execute
    preset_class = getattr(bpy.types, self.menu_idname)
AttributeError: 'RNA_Types' object has no attribute ''

Comment: No, it doesn't looks like. I've changed the preset_menu in the operator. Still the same Error.  But there is a bunch more of Stuff in the presets.py file. Maybe something from there is missing. I will looking for that Tomorrow. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yesss! Thank you so much :) There was just one line you wrote in the next Answer: preset_operator_defaults = {"menu_idname" : 'RPA_MT_Render_Preset_incl_Camera_Presets_Menu_to_all_Cams'}    Now it works everything how I expect it to. For now, I have now idea what that line means, but I will search for it.   Once, you wrote me, I should not use Operators in an Add-on. But, what if the Operator is written from my self in the same Add-on? Should I call that Operator from bpy.ops  or is there a smarter way?

Comment: it puts that into the operator call. `bpy.ops.foo.bar(filepath="path")` --> `bpy.ops.foo.bar(filepath="path", anotherthing=the_dict["anotherthing"])`  or more consisely `bpy.ops.foo.bar(**the_dict)`

Comment: Hopefully, there will be a day when I can find those things by myself ^^ . If I understand you right, you say, that "preset_operator_defaults"- line puts the modified preset_operator into the right place of Blender-Ops as a Dictionary. Great! And what do you think about the self written Operator-Call inside of the preset_operator with bpy.ops ?
Is there a smarter way for the call or will that do well? It works fine at the moment, just asking to avoid Errors in the future.

Comment: gives the values to assign to props when calling the operator. Another perhaps simpler method is to make  a default for the property. It was having `bpy.ops.foo.bar(classname="")` since there is no property with no name `bpy.types.<nothing here)` is getattri(bpy.types, classname)`.

Comment: Seemed to lose the comment re operators:  99% of time require operators when interfacing between user and UI.  IMO  These are the types of things  (using existing pre set code) that if you find yourself going nuts trying to bend blender to your will using existing code tools, re-writing makes all clearer.  Fan of `pathlib` https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f would be in a new one, or option to save presets to and load from text editor.

Comment: Added info to add the reset and post load preset callbacks to menu class.