# Where does Addpreset class get the preset url from

Tags: python

In Blender we can save and load preset using the preset.py file and the class Addpreset. These files are then written inside the preset folder inside the app script path. I would like to save and load preset from addon folder.

The save class save the files to the script folder with the next liens

```
target_path = os.path.join("presets",os.path.join("presets", self.preset_subdir))
target_path = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS',
                                              target_path,
                                              create=True)
```

What i cant figure out is, what part in that preset.py file loads the files. I was kinda expecting if i change those target paths, that both save and load would use them. The saving part i got working. But when i check the dropdown menu it states "missing path"

is see in the Types.Menu a description about props_filepath, im not familiar with this though

```
prop_filepath: Optional operator filepath property (defaults to "filepath").
```

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211543/15543

Comment: I saw that thread indeed, tried some other method but the default filepath is baked in deep i guess. My other idea is what i see is done with Sapling addon. This one has Enum menu, uses some pretty complicated method to read and excecute it.

I want to load the presets from the addon folder, the default method for blender write them to the app folder > presets > FOLDERNAME
i want to load and read from Addons > ADDONNAME > presets.